# Unhandled Exception compile error

Tags: c++, unhandled-exception

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

// Magical paper printing Method.. dont touch. (un)
static void print(string tempString, string tempString1, int end) {
    if (((tempString != "") && (tempString1 != "") && (end == 1))) {
        cout << tempString << " " << tempString1 << endl;
    } else if (((tempString != "") && (tempString1 != "") && (end == 0))) {
        cout << tempString << " " << tempString1;
    } else if (((tempString != "") &&& (tempString1 = "") && (end == 1))) {
        cout << tempString << endl;
    } else if (((tempString != "") && (tempString1 != "") && (end == 0))) {
        cout << tempString;
    } else {
        cout << "Error: inside Pandora_Box.print(), Could not print \n";
    }
}

// A rare method from the future that stops time.
static void threadSleep(int newMilliseconds) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(newMilliseconds));
}

//---------------------MAIN_SCREEN-----------------------------------------
class mainScreen {
public:
    static void newScreen(); 
    static void screen();
    static void loading();
};

void mainScreen::newScreen() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        cout << " " << endl;
    }
}

void mainScreen::screen() {
    cout << "===============================================================================" << endl;
    cout << "|=====================                                   =====================|" << endl;
    cout << "|                   []===================================[]                   |" << endl;
    cout << "|                   []                                   []                   |" << endl;
    cout << "|                   []  ===============================  []                   |" << endl;
    cout << "|                   []  | --------------------------- |  []                   |" << endl;
    cout << "|                   []  | Do you want to open the box |  []                   |" << endl;
    cout << "|                   []  | --------------------------- |  []                   |" << endl;
    cout << "|___________________[]  ===============================  []___________________|" << endl;
    cout << "|===================[]++                               ++[]===================|" << endl;
    cout << "|                     []_______________________________[]                     |" << endl;
    cout << "|                       []===========================[]                       |" << endl;
    cout << "|                         []__    |---------|    __[]                         |" << endl;
    cout << "|     [--------------]      []__  |   [=]   |  __[]      [--------------]     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     |++++++++++++++|      ++[]__|=========|__[]++      |++++++++++++++|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     [--------------]      ++                   ++      [--------------]     |" << endl;
    cout << "|                           ++                   ++                           |" << endl;
    cout << "|                           ++                   ++                           |" << endl;
    cout << "|                           ++  _______________  ++                           |" << endl;
    cout << "|                           ++__[]+++++++++++[]__++                           |" << endl;
    cout << "|                           ++[]+++++++++++++++[]++                           |" << endl;
    cout << "|                         __[]+++++++++++++++++++[]__                         |" << endl;
    cout << "|=======================[][][][][][][][]|[][][][][][][]=======================|" << endl;
    cout <<     "===============================================================================" << endl;

    string welcome_screen_var1; bool welcome_gate;

    getline(cin, welcome_screen_var1); 
    if ((welcome_screen_var1 == "yes") || (welcome_screen_var1 == "Yes")) {
        welcome_gate = true;
    } else if ((welcome_screen_var1 == "no") || (welcome_screen_var1 == "No")) {
        welcome_gate = true;
    } else {
        cout << "Error: Invalid input from -> welcome_screen_var1";
    }
}

void mainScreen::loading() {

    try {
        string loading_message[4] = { "Welcome", "Welcome to", "Welcome to    Pandora's", "Welcome to Pandora's Box" };

        threadSleep(300);
        newScreen();

        for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
            cout << "\t\t\t" << loading_message[j] << endl;
            threadSleep(600);
            newScreen();

            if (j == 4) {
                threadSleep(1000);
            }
        }
    } catch (const char* msg) {
        cout << msg << endl;
    }


}

//-------------------GAME_CORE--------------------------------------------
class gameCore {
public:
    static void gameLoop();
};

void gameCore::gameLoop() {

    // mainScreen gaemLoop Constructor
    mainScreen sc2;


    // Methods to Run
    sc2.screen();
    sc2.loading();
}

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main() {

    // Constructors;
    mainScreen sc;
    gameCore gc;

    // Methods in chrono. Order
    gc.gameLoop();


    //====Return&pause=====
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I searched for the error, I found many answers, but not a definite one, and they seemed to help just "their" code, anyway I couldn't find a way to fix it over time looking at stuff but here anyways.

When I compile the code (using visual studio community C++), I get a error,

error:

```
First-chance exception at 0x58627EA6 (msvcp120d.dll) in program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x4F377C2A.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

It runs pretty good and does it what it needs to do, but then it pops up with this error, also i know this probably has to do with the mainScreen::Loading() method.

I'm pretty new to C++ (about 2-3 weeks), so i don't know much, if anyone can maybe help with removing unnecessary lines, or structuring, that would be great.

Also if there is a question I may have not found, and a solution to this is on there, please reply, and thanks in advance..

Comment: That isn't a compile error; its a *runtime* error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
```

must be

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
```

in void mainScreen::loading().

as a consequence the test

```
if (j == 4)
```

should then be

```
if (j == 3)
```

Comment: Oh, thnx ^^ , forgot about the 0123 count thing. (-_-)